# How to submit apps to mac app store with xcode 3.2.5

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

Well I have developed a mac app with Xcode 3.2.5 . I have created the certificates and provisions also from mac app store. But the problem is .provisionprofile is not installing in Xcode. I am using Xcode 3.2.5. Can I not submit mac apps with this.

Do I have to update the Xcode to version 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must update to Xcode 4 in order to submit apps to the Mac App Store via Xcode.

You might be able to submit apps using the Application Loader app, but I imagine that it uses the same methods as Xcode would anyway...

Comment: With Apple there is never more than one way to do a thing :-) +1