# how to install .provisionprofile in xcode4 and code sign mac application

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, xcode4, provisioning-profile

Well Finally I upgrade xcode to version 4.0 as suggested by [Jasarien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76559/jasarien) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267470/how-to-submit-apps-to-mac-app-store-with-xcode-3-2-5)

I have created the application and installer certificate from mac developer protal. I have also created provisionprofile for the app. This file has extension of .provisionprofile. When I try to double click this file OSx tells me that there is no application to open this document.

I tried to drag this file over xcode4 application icon and xcode open it.. like preview app do. I tried to drag this file in organizer window but no luck. I also tried to import this from organizer -> provisioning profiles -> import button (at bottom of this window) but xcode is not allowing me to select .provisionprofile file.

So how .. how can I install (or import) this file in xcode 4 and sign my mac app. Anybody having any link to good step by step tutorial?

Anybody have uploaded mac apps on mac app store?

Anything guys? .. Seems like all mac developers are on holidays??

**This is first time with Stackoverflow that after offering bounty I am not getting any answer for a question... I thought xcode 4 and mac app store are hot topics now a days :)**

**I know many excellent mac developers are here, don't know why they are not intersted in my question. Should I edit my question to make it more clear. Or someone with good exp. with mac development can edit my question?**

Comment: I'm an iphone developer (not mac app), but I have to use the provisioning profiles as well. I normally just drag the file on XCode icon and the provisioning is added to Organizer window. Do you see the provisioning there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from apple dev... You have to be using Lion and Xcode4 for lion...

This really blows since I have some tools that require Rosetta in order to run. Now that Apple has removed Rosetta in lion this will complicate some product development and maintenance.

I will try this upgrade and see if it fixes the provision file problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to download the apple developer resources with safari.